# use SSL in an ios app for login

Tags: iphone, ios, encryption, ssl, authentication

So I am making an iPhone app for a startup that already has a rails site that uses SSL for their user logins, and I am trying to incorporate SSL into the iOS app.

I don't need any help (yet) with all the legal stuff regarding app store submission for an app that uses SSL, as I've found a lot of talk about all that.

I just need help with the basic how to incorporate SSL/encryption for sending an email and password in an HTTP POST request.

Thank you all in advance and let me know if you need more clarification!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to encrypt it yourself.

Just using a URL beginning with https will do it all for you.

I am using it for my app.